# Read from NFC tag with NDEF text

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, nfc

I'm trying to read from a NFC tag using following code:

```
    private void SubscribeToNFCMessage()
    {
        device.SubscribeForMessage("NDEF", (s, e) =>
            {
                DataReader reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(e.Data);
                string str = reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
            });
    }
```

When tapping the phone with the card the MessageReceivedHandler is executed. However, it throws a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException exception` when calling `reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);`

`e.Data.Length` value is 12, so is the value of `reader.UnconsumedBufferLength`

How should I read the data from the tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A NDEF message consists of several parts. Some parts of it might contain a string. But it cannot be directly converted into a string. So the error message is no surprise.

As decoding a NDEF message isn't trivial, I recommend using a library for it such as [NDEF Library for Proximity APIs (NFC).](http://ndef.codeplex.com/).

Examples how to use the library can be found directly on their home page.